# Tsung issue with crypto.so when testing https

Tags: openssl, erlang, tsung

I am using Tsung for load testing. I have set up Erlang/OTP R16B03-1 and Tsung 1.5.1 on CentOS 6.4 and openssl 1.0.1e-fips. Everything was successfully compiled except when running ./configure for Tsung, there is a warning:

> WARNING: ssl application is not working properly !!!

Now when I run Tsung to load testing my https server, it gives me this error:

> Unable to load crypto library. Failed with error: "load_failed, Failed
>   to load NIF library:
>   '/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/crypto-3.2/priv/lib/crypto.so: undefined
>   symbol: EC_GROUP_new_curve_GF2m'" OpenSSL might not be installed on
>   this system.

I am aware of the openssl EC crypto issues in Centos/RHEL (See http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2014-February/076760.html) but did not find the solution to this problem.
Should I update openssl or recompile Erlang with no EC option?

Comment: Did you find solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it! Just reinstall erlang from sources. I downloaded 17-th version of it. 
http://www.erlang.org/download/otp_src_17.0.tar.gz
And everythign works fine!
Also check this out:
https://github.com/ngocdaothanh/tsart/blob/master/amazonlinux.md

Everything is cool there except version of Erlang and Tsung. So I choosed 17-th version of erlang and 1.5.1 of Tsung. I spent almost 2 days to configure it.